# guava google code cartesian

Tags: java, guava, cartesian

Is there anyway to do a Cartesian product on 15 integer sets of size 5 ?
It seems like the library is throwing an exception error: cartesian product too big !

Comment: Can you show us what method you're referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes it is Sets.cartesianproduct().

Comment: It's not integer overflow, however, the size of the product I described is 5^15. I am trying to find a way to get around this. 
In fact, since AxBxC = (AxB)xC, I wanna be able to remove some of the sets after each product (according to the problem structure)...

Comment: Yes, it's integer overflow; `Sets.cartesianProduct` rejects products that would have size greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I see. Is there anything to go around it ? Potentially I can write my own function, but I guess this one is more efficient in terms of memory.

Comment: What would you even do with a Cartesian product that big, is the question?  If you can filter some of the sets down, then do that first.

Answer (score 1):

The [error message](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/CartesianList.java#L59) explains the issue:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Cartesian product too large; must have size at most Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

The Cartesian product of 15 5-length sets produces 5^15 different results, or 30,517,578,125. Because a `Set` cannot have a `size()` larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it's not possible to (correctly) return such a large set. As Louis Wasserman points out, it's somewhat unlikely you really want to operate on such a large number of results, since constructing 30 billion lists is expensive no matter how you do it. Your best bet may be to re-examine the problem and see if there's some solution that avoids needing to construct so many results.

If you don't actually need `Set` semantics you can of course construct all the Cartesian sets one by one simply enough with nested for loops (as described in the [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-)):

```
for (B b0 : sets.get(0)) {
  for (B b1 : sets.get(1)) {
    ...
    ImmutableList<B> tuple = ImmutableList.of(b0, b1, ...);
    // operate on tuple
  }
}
```

But of course don't try to store them all in a single collection - you'll get an error as you exceed the maximum size of the collection (or your heap space).